# data uri as background image of svg not converted to canvas on safari live site

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, d3.js, svg

I want to convert one svg having base64 png data uri as background image .

Its working on firefox , chrome & safari on local machine.
But its not working on safari on live site.

Is there any issues with live site that safari is not allowing data uri?

Please help.

```
  var svgContainer = d3.select('#chart')
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 500)
                    .attr("height", 500)
                    .attr("style", "background-color: #f6f6f6;background-image: url('" + stress_shifter.chart_background_image_base64 +  "');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 50%;")
                    .attr("id", "stress_shifter_svg");
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var img = new Image();
        //var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml"});

        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
```

Comment: There is probably some code missing in your question.

Comment: Let me check and add it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is working

```
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    //var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

    var png = '';
    var emailConfirmationMessage = '';
    var img1 = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 136, 136);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        sendEmail(canvas,DOMURL);

    };

     img1.onload = function(){
       img.src = url;
     };
    img1.src = 'chart1.png';
```